# Eclipse doesn't detect my Android device GT-S6810L

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, device, android-debug

I'm using Eclipse + ADT, and my physical device (listed below) is unlisted on Android Device Chooser. I have updated Eclipse and all of the Android packages. My phone is running Android KitKat, which corresponds to the target version listed in the Eclipse Project.

Also, the reason I decided to try testing on a real device is because the emulator doesn't seem to be working right anymore when I run my project. The emulator launches, but the program never does. Any ideas?

(using windows 7)

Comment: did you enable debugging on your phone ?

Comment: ... and did you install drivers ... asked many times here

Comment: `because the emulator doesn't seem to be working right anymore when I run my project` makes me think that the project is broken...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay there can be a few reasons for so...
try a few things i mention below.

1) check your phone driver is installed and updated to latest..

Go to : Settings -> Applications -> Development to enable USB debugging

1. Plug in device USB
2. Desktop "My Computer" right click -> "Manager"
3. Choose "Device Manager"
4. Portable Device
5. right click on your device -> "Update Driver software" -> Search
   automatically (wait about 3-5min)

2) check if adb read your device

Go to : adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools

1. press shit+rightclick -> Open command window here
2. type adb devices (adb should list your currently pluged in device)
3. if not listed then just try restarting ADB. (you can use the
   commands: adb kill-server followed by adb start-server).